# cannot create a property 'mark' on string

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am new to Gulp. I have two tasks:

```
gulp.task('jadehtml', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};
  gulp.src('source/jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
// End Gulp Jade 

// default task

//  sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('source/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

Now they work perfectly fine when run individually. But when I use the `gulp.watch()` command they give me an error. Here is my `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('source/jade/*.jade', 'jadehtml');
  gulp.watch('source/scss/*.scss', 'sass');
});
```

This is the error:

[image: Error for Gulp]

Answer (score 29):

The [`tasks` parameter](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#tasks) that you pass to `gulp.watch()` **always** has to be an array, even if it's just one task. So instead of this:

```
gulp.watch('source/jade/*.jade', 'jadehtml');
gulp.watch('source/scss/*.scss', 'sass');
```

You need to do this:

```
gulp.watch('source/jade/*.jade', ['jadehtml']);
gulp.watch('source/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
```